# Account model in MVC app doesn't work after deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, authentication

I have an MVC app that I deployed to test on my machine (IIS on XP).  I am unable to login using credentials I have set up using the ASP.NET configuration.  Everything works fine before I published app.  After typing in my username and password, the app doesn't seem to recognize it and gives the follwoing error message

![enter image description here][1]

Comment: wasn't able to upload image......but the error message stated that "Login was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again." and that the fields were required (even though I entered them correctly

Comment: What kind of authentication are you trying to use?

Comment: New to MVC..........I have set up authentication via ASP.NET Configuration.

Answer (score 1):

By default, a new MVC project is configured to use the Membership Provider with SQLExpress using a file called aspnetdb.mdf in your App_Data folder.  When you published, did that file make it to the destination?

To verify this is the issue, check your web.config.  Look for the membership tag and the providers tag underneath that.  Locate the AspNetSqlMembershipProvider provider and check its connection string.  It will likely say ApplicationServices if you haven't changed it from the default.  Then, check the ConnectionStrings node in your web.config to verify what database the Membership Provider is trying to use and where it's located.

Comment: Thanks Nathan!  I verified the settings, re-published, and now it works fine.